# Batchh file arguments processing

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments

Say i have a batch file called check.bat. I am running it on java using the command

> ```
> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\check.bat");
> ```

It runs the batch file with no issues. But when i pass arguments to the batch file like,

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\check.bat arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4");

i want to access these arguments inside check.bat
I am aware that %* gets me all arguments. But what i want is all the arguments except for the last argument as a single variable. 
Very new to batch files. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method suggested by SomethingDark (combining the parameters before you call your batch file) is probably the best, but if you aren't able to use it, the following may help (you may need to experiment if your parameters contain characters that have special meaning to Windows):

```
@echo off
        setlocal
        set ALLBUT1=
        if "%~2" == "" goto :gotthem
        set ALLBUT1=%1
:loop
        shift
        if "%~2" == "" goto :gotthem
        set "ALLBUT1=%ALLBUT1% %1"
        goto :loop
:gotthem
        set "LAST=%1"

        echo All-but-one:%ALLBUT1%:
        echo Last:%LAST%:
```

which gives:

```
S:\>arg one two three
All-but-one:one two:
Last:three:

S:\>arg one two three four
All-but-one:one two three:
Last:four:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working superfine :)

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, you would be able to take the first three arguments as one giant argument by putting them in quotes like `check.bat "arg1 arg2 arg3" arg4`

Since this is in Java, you should be able to escape some quotes into the exec command, like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\check.bat \"arg1 arg2 arg3\" arg4");`

And if for some reason that doesn't work, you can always just take the four arguments in batch and do whatever you want to them inside the batch script.

```
@echo off
set first_three="%1 %2 %3"
set last_one=%4
```